# do loop within data step with unresolve variables

Tags: sas

I have several parameters from `proc sql select into:` and I would like to store all of them to a dataset named `parm`. The following is the code I attempted:

I got the following parameter from previous step:

```
%let count = 4;
%let yymm1 = '1505';
%let yymm2 = '1504';
%let yymm3 = '1503';
%let yymm4 = '1502';
```

Here is the data step:

```
data parm;
    format yymm1 - yymm&count. $4.;
    array A(*) yymm1-yymm&count.;
    do i = 1 to &count.;
        A(i) = "&&yymm&i";
    end;
run;
```

Problem is that &i and &&yymm cannot be resolved.

Comment: You're mis-combining macro variables and data step variables.  In any event, you should have your `proc sql` step create this dataset.

Comment: Please delight me how i can achieve that with proc sql?

Comment: `create table <whatever> as select <whatever>`.

Comment: Why do your macro variable values include quotes?

Comment: You should define the length of the variables in your ARRAY statement.  array a $6 yymm1-yymm&count ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I echo @Joe 's comment, here are my suggestions on your given situation. First make sure if the macro variable values contain single quotes or NOT. You have it in your macro variable definition, while length=4 in your data step won't cut it for you. Then like @Joe suggested, you need to separate your macro variable and data step variable by doing something like the following:

```
%let count = 4;
%let yymm1 = '1505';
%let yymm2 = '1504';
%let yymm3 = '1503';
%let yymm4 = '1502';

data parm;
    format yymm1 - yymm&count. $6.;
    array A(*) yymm1-yymm&count.;

    do i = 1 to &count.;
        A(i) = symget(cats('yymm',i));
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Why did you attach $6 format to the new variables? If you want to set the length of the variables in the ARRAY do it in the ARRAY statement.

Comment: @Tom, After copy and paste, doing so will allow me to type the least. And you are right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are referencing the undefined macro variable I.  Notice that your DO loop is creating the data set variable I.  Either recode to use a macro %DO loop or modify the program to use the value of the data set variable I to build the name of the macro variable you want to retrieve.

```
do i=1 to dim(a); 
   a(i) = symget(cats('yymm',i));
end;
```